# Tool to see object references

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, backbone-views

Is there a tool for Node.js or the browser whereby I can find out which objects hold a reference to object X?

Right now I am using Backbone for front-end development and even though I remove views there still seem to be references to them afterwards.

The reason I suspect this behavior in the first place is because I am using plugin/addons for Backbone debugging in Chrome and Mozilla.

This does make me wonder if perhaps these programs themselves are the ones holding references to the Backbone objects!

Answer (score 3):

First of all,Sadly there is no way to do that.
You can check who calls a function and object which specific variable holds as reference though.
It's not because of Backbone/Node.js but Javascript itself.
When you substitute object/Array, javascript only passes target memory address to the variable.

But I assume it's highly possible that the reason why you are having memory leak problem is not because of references from another variables but event handlers which is often seen in Backbone uses(also knowns as "zombie view")

Once you set events handler in a View, You need to make sure all events are unset before you actually delete the view(`.remove()`) unless You are using only `listenTo` for Backbone events and `this.$el` for  jQuery events.
Because events set via `listenTo` and `this.$el` are automatically removed by Backbone Core when you remove a View.
And events set by `Model.on` or global jQuery`$` would not be so.

So Please check your whole code whether You are using `.on` or global jQuery Object to set events, in the case You have, replace them into `listenTo` or `this.$el.on` or manually unset them Before You remove them.

Comment: yeah, I am using this.listenTo etc, and I still have zombie views - I read all about that phenomenon and have done my best to prevent it - I seriously think it might be the observing plugins for Chrome and Mozilla that hold onto references for the Backbone views...will let you know what I find out